# Django syncdb error in modules

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

After i enter this code models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode


# Create your models here.
class SignUp(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120 , null = True , blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120 , null = True , blank = True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True , auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False , auto_now = True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.email)  # return self.email
```

i got this error when i syncdb

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\src>python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in pop
ulate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in impor
t_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Paramesh\Desktop\project\src\signup\models.py", line 11
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False , auto_now = True)
                                                                         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

iam new django before this everything run with out errors

I don't get the what is the error

i tried removing the timestamp it does not work

Comment: File "C:\Users\Paramesh\Desktop\project\src\signup\models.py", line 11  

   ` updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False , auto_now = True)`

Comment: Your code has mixed levels of indentation. There is nothing wrong with the code per se

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have spaces mixed with tabs in your line indentation. Set your IDE to display space and tab characters and then replace the tabs with spaces.

Comment: How can i do that in sublime text 3

Comment: With the default sublime text 3 configuration, simply selecting the code lines will do. The spaces will be displayed as dots and the tabs as lines.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tab character before timestamp. You should either use spaces or tabs to indent Python, never both.